# pyinstaller single exe of program which uses google api client lib

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, google-api-python-client

I have a python program which I've successfully packaged up as a single exe using pyinstaller in the past. Recently I added new features which make use of the google api python client ( https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/ ). I've attempted to make a new single exe package of the new version and it fails to run.

I enable debugging and the console and initially the issue was that it hadn't picked up the oauth lib. I fixed that by adding the following to my spec file:

```
hiddenimports=['googleapiclient', 'apiclient']
```

When I build I can see this:

```
53092 INFO: Hidden import 'googleapiclient' has been found otherwise
53093 INFO: Hidden import 'apiclient' has been found otherwise
```

However, now when I run the rebuilt exe I get the following error before it exits:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: google-api-python-client
```

I can't see any reference to that and I'm not sure how to force it to be packaged up with the exe.

I figure I can't be the only person to have ever wanted to package up a python program that makes use of the google api, but I failed to find any help during a lot of time with my friend google...

Any tips?

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post. I fixed the oauth issue by adding `hiddenimports=['oauth2client']` when trying to fix the NotFound: google-api-python-client issue I tried `hiddenimports=['googleapiclient', 'apiclient', 'oauth2client']`

Answer (score 3):

Many People Have same question but I can't find any answer

Try This way

1. find site package of your project
2. enter the Pyinstaller/hooks and find hokk-google.api_core.py
3. add line ( edit line ) datas += copy_metadata('google-api-python-client')

example

`from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
datas = copy_metadata('google-api-core')
datas += copy_metadata('google-api-python-client')`

4. excute pyinstaller  hidden-import google-api-python-client

pyinstaller --hidden-import google-api-python-client

5. you can avoid error
   pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: google-api-python-client

Comment: This should be the selected answer! It solved my issue at least :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to dig deeper into this issue after I switched from using pip to easy_install to install the google-api-python-client package. Manually installing the egg file gave me a much neater way of testing.

I then started building using pyinstaller with out the --onefile option, this way I was able to start messing with the egg file that was packaged up with my program. Eventually I found out that my problem was stemming from the fact I'm making use of Pandas and the Google API.

[Here's the relevant Pandas bug on github.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/403f38da35ab04d3997f61db3c98134fe02910d3)

To solve the problem I had to update my version of Pandas.

I did find that if I moved to the most recent version of Pandas (1.6.0) I ran into a new issue because it imports dateutil and it causes problems looking for the zoneinfo file. I've landed on Pandas 1.5.1 and it is all working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add site-packages using:

--add-data "path_to_your_package:package_name(e.g googleapiclient)"